# Set Virtual Attribute Rails Active Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

How do I set a virtual attribute that sets the first and last name, when I call Quote.new()?

The before_save :assign_name method does not seem work. I get an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `before_save' for Quote:Class
```

CONTROLLER:

```
  quote = {name: "John Doe", City: "New York"}
  Quote.new(quote)
```

MODEL:

```
class Quote
    include ActiveModel::Model

    before_save :assign_name

    attr_accessor :name, :first, :last, :city


    def assign_name
      title_split = self.name.split(" / ")
      self.first = title_split[0]
      self.last = title_split[1]
    end
end
```

Comment: Btw `before_save` is an ActiveRecord callback. Not ActiveModel. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
class Quote
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :first, :last, :city

  def initialize(attributes={})
    super
    assign_name(name)
  end

  def assign_name(name)
    title_split = name.split(" / ")
    self.first = title_split[0]
    self.last = title_split[1]
  end
end
```

Also link to documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html)

Comment: Worked great, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`before_save` is defined in ActiveRecord. You need to let your class inherit from ActiveRecord::Base as the following:

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And if you put the method in "before_save" callback, that means the method will be called only when Quote#save is executed. For example,

```
quote = {name: "John Doe", City: "New York"}
q = Quote.new(quote)
q.save
```